# MongoDB issue with NumberLong

Tags: mongodb

we are using a script to copy some data from an older mongo version to mongo 3.6.
Works great.  To speed it up, we decided to multi-thread it.  We've broken up the collection by number of records, divided by number of threads we want to run.

So for a 2.5 billion row table, we run 20 threads, and do the following to get the object IDs, and then use a range of the object IDs per thread: (first 2 shown)

```
db.m_audit_event.find().sort(['_id']).skip(133432757).pretty().limit(1).next()._id;
db.m_audit_event.find().sort(['_id']).skip(266865514).pretty().limit(1).next()._id;
```

And it will return an Object ID, i.e.

```
ObjectId("5976e3af2276c74c154b1c67")
```

This works fine, until we hit a larger number, and then mongo shell returns...

```
error: { "$err" : "bad skip value in query", "code" : 10105 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js
```

So I tried to modify the above using NumberLong, like so:

```
db.m_audit_event.find().sort(['_id']).skip(NumberLong(2268356869)).pretty().limit(1).next()._id;
```

I also tried with quotes:

```
db.m_audit_event.find().sort(['_id']).skip(NumberLong("2268356869")).pretty().limit(1).next()._id;
```

But same result, both attempts return "bad skip value in query"

Any ideas on how to query mongo so it works with larger numbers?

Comment: Ah, so looking like the skip function in Mongo only supports 32 bit int, which max value is  2,147,483,647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $skip takes a positive **integer** that specifies the maximum number of documents to skip.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/#pipe._S_skip

**Workaround:** (We cannot use `long` to skip documents (> 2<sup>31</sup> − 1), but we can use [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) with several `$skip`'s)

```
db.m_audit_event.aggregate([
  {
    $skip: 1000000000
  },
  {
    $skip: 1000000000
  },
  {
    $skip: 268356869
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
]).next()._id
```

Comment: Thank you, thats perfect.  I didn't realize you could aggregate skips like that.

Comment: actually, when I run above, Im getting back TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'next'

Comment: @tman What is your MongoDB version and what driver are you using to execute this aggregation? Try to use `.toArray()[0]._id` instead of `.next()`

Comment: Mongo version is 3.6.16, and right now Im just running this directly via mongo shell.  But using pymongo 3.4.0, as using a later version wasn't able to communicate with the older mongo version and newer.  Will try the .toArray method, thank you

Comment: I can leave off the .next() and see the array results, which for my needs is "good enough".  I tried replacing with next() with toArray, but got back TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toArray'

Comment: @tman print : `db.m_audit_event.aggregate(...)` result to see what you get. In your case, It seems aggregate doesnt return Cursor, but result